# Alphabetically sort in Linked Lists in C?

Tags: c, sorting

I am trying to sort the names in this linked list alphabetically but I not sure which would be a right approach to take. I created a method to compare the names in the list and update my current pointer each time. I keep getting errors. Could anyone suggest a better way to sort through the names? I am new to C and I am struggling to find a better way to implement this. Any help would be massively appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define HOW_MANY  7

char *names[HOW_MANY] = { "Ben", "Chris", "RDJ", "Mark", "Scarlet", "Samuel", "Tom" };
int ages[HOW_MANY] = { 22, 24, 50, 26, 18, 32, 24 };

/* declare your struct for a person here */
struct person {
    char *name;
    int age;
    struct person *next;
};

static struct person *compare_people(struct person *headptr, struct person *headptr) {
    int didSwap = 1, limit = HOW_MANY - 1;
    struct person *temp;
    struct person *previous = headptr;
    struct person *new = headptr -> next;

    while (didSwap) {
        didSwap = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
            if (strcmp(previous->name, new->name) > 0) {
                temp = previous;
                previous = new;
                new = temp;
                didSwap = 1;
            }
        }
        limit--;
    }
    return temp;
}

static struct person *insert_sorted(struct person *headptr, char *name, int age) {
    struct person *ptr;
    // Allocate heap space for a record
    ptr = malloc(sizeof(struct person));
    if (ptr == NULL)
        abort();
    // Assign to structure fields
    ptr->name = name;
    ptr->age = age;
    ptr->next = NULL;

    if (headptr == NULL) {
        ptr->next = headptr;
        headptr = ptr;
    } else {
        struct person *currptr = headptr;

        while (currptr != NULL) {
            currptr = compare_people(headptr, headptr);
        }
        headptr = currptr;
    }
    return headptr;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    // initialise the pointer  to be empty
    struct person *headptr = NULL;

    // To insert all the info in the array
    for (int i = 0; i < HOW_MANY ; i++) {
        headptr = insert_sorted(headptr, names[i], ages[i]);
    }

    struct person *current = headptr;
    while (current != NULL) {
        printf("The person's name is %s and the age is %d.\n", current->name, current->age);
        current = current->next;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Check the start of the list. If that element is lexicographically greater than your word you want to insert, check the next element. Repeat. If you find one that is lexicographically less than your word, then insert the word there.

Comment: Linked lists lend themselves very naturally to mergesort. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35614098/implementing-mergesort-on-a-linked-list/35616981#35616981

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your approach is too complicated: the comparison function performs some kind of sorting and the insert function too.  The comparison function should return an `int` whose value would be negative, 0 or positive, like `strcmp()`, and the insert_sorted should insert the new `person` into the list at the appropriate position using a simple iterative method.

Here is a simpler version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define HOW_MANY  7

char *names[HOW_MANY] = { "Ben", "Chris", "RDJ", "Mark", "Scarlet", "Samuel", "Tom" };
int ages[HOW_MANY] = { 22, 24, 50, 26, 18, 32, 24 };

/* declare your struct for a person here */
struct person {
    char *name;
    int age;
    struct person *next;
};

static int compare_people(const struct person *a, const struct person *b) {
     return strcmp(a->name, b->name);
}

static struct person *insert_sorted(struct person *headptr, char *name, int age) {
    // Allocate heap space for a record
    struct person *ptr = malloc(sizeof(struct person));
    if (ptr == NULL) {
        abort();
    }

    // Assign to structure fields
    ptr->name = name;
    ptr->age = age;
    ptr->next = NULL;

    struct person **pp = &headptr;
    while (*pp != NULL && compare_people(ptr, *pp) >= 0) {
        pp = &(*pp)->next;
    }
    ptr->next = *pp;
    *pp = ptr;

    return headptr;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    // initialise the list to be empty
    struct person *headptr = NULL;

    // To insert all the info in the array
    for (int i = 0; i < HOW_MANY; i++) {
        headptr = insert_sorted(headptr, names[i], ages[i]);
    }

    struct person *current = headptr;
    while (current != NULL) {
        printf("The person's name is %s and the age is %d.\n", current->name, current->age);
        current = current->next;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT:** below is an alternate version with simple pointers. You can see that I need to make a special case of the empty list and of insertion at the start.

```
static struct person *insert_sorted(struct person *headptr, char *name, int age) {
    // Allocate heap space for a record
    struct person *ptr = malloc(sizeof(struct person));
    if (ptr == NULL) {
        abort();
    }
    ptr->name = name;
    ptr->age = age;
    ptr->next = NULL;

    if (headptr == NULL || compare_people(ptr, headptr) < 0) {
        ptr->next = headptr;
        return ptr;
    } else {
        struct person *cur = headptr;
        while (cur->next != NULL && compare_people(ptr, cur->next) >= 0) {
            cur = cur->next;
        }
        ptr->next = cur->next;
        cur->next = ptr;
        return headptr;
    }
}
```

Comment: And if you want to sort by ascending age, just replace in the function `compare_people()` the `return strcmp(a->name, b->name);` by the `return (a->age > b->age);`...

Comment: @J.Piquard: for consistency, the `compare_age` should return a signed status; `return (a->age > b->age) - (a->age < b->age);`

Comment: @chqrlie Could you explain me a few things.. as I am new in C.    Is there a major difference between “struct person *currptr “ vs “struct person* currptr”? 

Alternatively could I have used this 
`                  struct person *currptr = headptr;
                    
                    while (currptr != NULL && compare_people(ptr,currptr) > 0) {
                        currptr = currptr -> next;
                    }
                    ptr -> next = currptr;
                    currptr = ptr; `

Comment: Sorry I couldn't get the indentation working properly?

Comment: @chqrlie Is it very important to make a pointer of a pointer and then assign it to the address of the headptr? Couldn't I just use a pointer of currptr and assign it to headptr?

Comment: @ShamveelAhammed: my solution uses a pointer to pointer `pp` to avoid making a special case of the empty list and the singleton.  Otherwise, you cannot use the loop with `currptr` because you must keep the previous pointer to insert the new node *before* the current one if it is less than the current one.  I shall add an alternate version for you to see the difference.

Comment: @chqlrile I completely forgot about that.. It makes sense, as we use the previous pointer later on.... Thanks for the help :)... Could you also explain me is there major difference between using `struct person *headptr ` vs `struct person* headptr`. ?.... Because I see ppl using them both ways in C programs.

Comment: @ShamveelAhammed: the spacing before or after the `*` is a matter of coding convention.  putting the `*` next to the variable name stresses the fact that the variable is a pointer. The C syntax for declarations allows multiple variables to be defined in one statement potentially mixing pointers and objects: `int *p, i;` defines an integer `i` and a pointer to `int` `p`.  Tacking the `*` to the type such as in `int* p, q;` is confusing as this statement does **not** define 2 pointers.